# Android - start an activity from command line using intent uri

Tags: android, android-intent, adb, intentfilter, url-scheme

I have an Activity A with the following intent filter

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.comp.pac.ActivityA">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="customapp"
                  android:host="show"
                  android:path="/"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I am basically trying the custom data scheme in intent filters as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/intents)

To test whether the IntentUri launches the activity or not I'm trying to fire the intent using the following command through terminal :

```
adb shell am start intent://show/#Intent;scheme=customapp;package=com.comp.pac;end
```

I get the following error :

```
Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=intent://show/ flg=0x10000000 }
```

**Question : Is there anything wrong with the command? If not, what is the easiest way to test whether the intent uri starts the activity?**

The instructions for using the `adb` command to start activity using intent uri is available [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#am).

Comment: adb shell 'am start "intent:////show/#Intent;scheme=customapp;package=com.comp.pac;end"'                                 it will solve your problem it will launch your activity

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to use `""`:

```
adb shell 'am start "intent:#Intent;scheme=customapp;package=com.comp.pac;end"'
```

Answer (score 6):

enter code hereAnother way to open activity :

```
$ adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "example://gizmos" com.example.android
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to run an Activity from the shell:

`adb shell am start com.example.hello/.MainActivity`

Note the "/" after the `package` name and the "." before the `Activity` name.